# Why does this JSON string return NULL?

Tags: php, json

I have the following PHP script with the working (according to [`JsonViewer`](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)) JSON string:

```
<?php
$string = "{0:{'id':1,'name':'Antiek en Kunst','subs':[{'id':2,'name':'Antiek | Bestek'},{'id':3,'name':'Antiek | Boeken en Bijbels'},{'id':1100,'name':'Antiek | Emaille'},{'id':1501,'name':'Antiek | Gereedschap en Instrumenten'},{'id':1648,'name':'Antiek | Glas en Kristal'},{'id':2614,'name':'Antiek | Goud en Zilver'},{'id':2661,'name':'Antiek | Kandelaars'},{'id':1841,'name':'Antiek | Kantoor en Zakelijk'},{'id':1502,'name':'Antiek | Keramiek en Aardewerk'},{'id':1842,'name':'Antiek | Keukenbenodigdheden'},{'id':2118,'name':'Antiek | Kleden en Textiel'},{'id':1503,'name':'Antiek | Kleding en Accessoires'},{'id':6,'name':'Antiek | Klokken'},{'id':1647,'name':'Antiek | Koper en Brons'},{'id':7,'name':'Antiek | Lampen'},{'id':1504,'name':'Antiek | Meubels | Bedden'},{'id':5,'name':'Antiek | Meubels | Kasten'},{'id':1505,'name':'Antiek | Meubels | Stoelen en Banken'},{'id':1506,'name':'Antiek | Meubels | Tafels'},{'id':1101,'name':'Antiek | Naaimachines'},{'id':10,'name':'Antiek | Porselein'},{'id':1102,'name':'Antiek | Religie'},{'id':1103,'name':'Antiek | Schalen'},{'id':2662,'name':'Antiek | Schoolplaten'},{'id':1843,'name':'Antiek | Servies compleet'},{'id':12,'name':'Antiek | Servies los'},{'id':1507,'name':'Antiek | Speelgoed'},{'id':2663,'name':'Antiek | Spiegels'},{'id':2664,'name':'Antiek | Tin'},{'id':11,'name':'Antiek | Tv\'s en Audio'},{'id':14,'name':'Antiek | Vazen'},{'id':1104,'name':'Antiek | Wandborden en Tegels'},{'id':1500,'name':'Antiek | Woonaccessoires'},{'id':9,'name':'Antiek | Overige'},{'id':15,'name':'Curiosa en Brocante'},{'id':1423,'name':'Diensten | Kunstenaars en Portretschilders'},{'id':2610,'name':'Diensten | Reparatie en Onderhoud'},{'id':23,'name':'Kunst | Beelden en Houtsnijwerken'},{'id':1508,'name':'Kunst | Designobjecten'},{'id':1105,'name':'Kunst | Etsen en Gravures'},{'id':27,'name':'Kunst | Litho\'s en Zeefdrukken'},{'id':1844,'name':'Kunst | Niet-Westerse kunst'},{'id':1846,'name':'Kunst | Schilderijen | Abstract'},{'id':25,'name':'Kunst | Schilderijen | Klassiek'},{'id':1845,'name':'Kunst | Schilderijen | Modern'},{'id':26,'name':'Kunst | Tekeningen en Foto\'s'},{'id':24,'name':'Kunst | Overige'}]},1:{'id':31,'name':'Audio, Tv en Foto','subs':[{'id':2035,'name':'Accu\'s en Batterijen'},{'id':2617,'name':'Afstandsbedieningen'},{'id':32,'name':'Bandrecorders'},{'id':1132,'name':'Beamers'},{'id':2665,'name':'Blu-ray-spelers en Blu-ray-recorders'},{'id':33,'name':'Buizenversterkers'},{'id':2036,'name':'Cassettedecks'},{'id':35,'name':'Cd-spelers'},{'id':2666,'name':'Diaprojectors'},{'id':2042,'name':'Diensten | Film- en Videobewerking'},{'id':1199,'name':'Diensten | Fotografen'},{'id':1219,'name':'Diensten | Reparaties'},{'id':1114,'name':'Dvd-spelers en Dvd-recorders'},{'id':1115,'name':'Films 8mm, 16mm en 35mm'},{'id':1360,'name':'Fotografie | Accu\'s en Batterijen'},{'id':480,'name':'Fotografie | Camera\'s | Analoog'},{'id':487,'name':'Fotografie | Camera\'s | Digitaal'},{'id':2667,'name':'Fotografie | Digitale fotolijstjes'},{'id':488,'name':'Fotografie | Doka Toebehoren'},{'id':1720,'name':'Fotografie | Filters'},{'id':489,'name':'Fotografie | Flitsers'},{'id':1483,'name':'Fotografie | Fotolijsten en Fotoalbums'},{'id':1721,'name':'Fotografie | Fotoprinters en Fotopapier'},{'id':1400,'name':'Fotografie | Fotostudio en Toebehoren'},{'id':1484,'name':'Fotografie | Fototassen'},{'id':493,'name':'Fotografie | Geheugenkaarten'},{'id':495,'name':'Fotografie | Lenzen en Objectieven'},{'id':497,'name':'Fotografie | Onderwatercamera\'s'},{'id':501,'name':'Fotografie | Professionele apparatuur'},{'id':500,'name':'Fotografie | Statieven en Balhoofden'},{'id':1722,'name':'Harddiskrecorders'},{'id':1116,'name':'Home Cinema-sets'},{'id':1106,'name':'Kabels'},{'id':37,'name':'Koptelefoons en Headsets'},{'id':38,'name':'Luidsprekers'},{'id':2668,'name':'Mediaspelers'},{'id':40,'name':'Mp3-spelers | Apple iPod'},{'id':1649,'name':'Mp3-spelers | Overige merken'},{'id':1723,'name':'Mp3-spelers | Accessoires | Apple iPod'},{'id':1452,'name':'Mp3-spelers | Accessoires | Overige merken'},{'id':2615,'name':'Mp4-spelers'},{'id':1724,'name':'Opladers'},{'id':496,'name':'Optische apparatuur | Microscopen'},{'id':502,'name':'Optische apparatuur | Telescopen'},{'id':503,'name':'Optische apparatuur | Verrekijkers'},{'id':42,'name':'Platenspelers en Pick-ups'},{'id':1117,'name':'Professionele Audio-, Tv- en Video-apparatuur'},{'id':43,'name':'Radio\'s'},{'id':36,'name':'Stereo-sets'},{'id':45,'name':'Tuners'},{'id':1118,'name':'Tv-decoders en Schotelantennes'},{'id':1120,'name':'Tv\'s | Plasma, Lcd en Led'},{'id':1121,'name':'Tv\'s | Overige Tv\'s'},{'id':1453,'name':'Tv\'s | Accessoires'},{'id':46,'name':'Versterkers en Receivers'},{'id':1129,'name':'Videobewakingsapparatuur'},{'id':1130,'name':'Videocamera\'s | Analoog'},{'id':1131,'name':'Videocamera\'s | Digitaal'},{'id':1133,'name':'Videospelers en Videorecorders'},{'id':47,'name':'Walkmans, Discmans en Minidiscspelers'},{'id':1725,'name':'Weerstations en Barometers'},{'id':41,'name':'Overige Audio, Tv en Foto'}]}}";

var_dump(json_decode($string)); // returns null
?>
```

Why does this give me `null`?

Comment: Because your JSON string is invalid? (http://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: Not a valid Json.

According to the state machine diagram on the JSON website, only escaped double-quote characters are allowed, not single-quotes. Single quote characters do not need to be escaped
read more : http://www.json.org/

[image]

For your reference, you can also validate your JSON quickly [here](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Associative arrays require the keys to be strings and not integers.

Valid:

`{"0":[]}`

Invalid:

`{0:[]}`

Answer (score 1):

Because it's not [JSON](http://json.org/). Strings use double quotes, not single.